# VSC: How to auto close curly brackets in f-strings

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Hi I want to ask if it's possible to enable auto closing curly brackets in f-strings in Visual Studio Code. In Python you use often f-strings and therefore you need curly brackets.

```py
print(f"Hello {name}!")
```

I already found something but I don't know if that feature is already implemented and if not if I can implement it with external plugins?: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/13673

Comment: Please add a language tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the "Always" Auto Closing Brackets setting, but limit it to Python in your settings.json:

```
"[python]": {
    "editor.autoClosingBrackets": "always"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

VS Code has this auto closing brackets feature built-in in the editor. It's just disabled by default if you use it inside a string. To make it always close the brackets, Go to `File > Preferences > Text Editor > Auto Closing Brackets` then change the value from 'languageDefined' to 'Always'. [The Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7AP2.png).

Comment: If this works, wouldn't it also auto-close in many environments other than f-string curly braces in Python?

Comment: @Noah yup I think it'll also auto close in another language.